# Replacing char in [row][col] index replaces all characters in col

Tags: python

Currently I am trying to place a word in a column of 2D array in Python 3.6

```
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.board = [["."] * 10] * 10
        self.board[0][0] = 'T'

    def printBoardToTerminal(self):
        for index in range(0,10):
            print()
            print(self.board[index], end=" ")
```

**Expected**:

```
['T', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
```

**Actual**:

```
['T', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['T', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['T', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['T', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['T', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['T', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['T', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['T', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['T', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['T', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
```

I thought it was a printing error but when I `print(self.board)` it also shows that the first element in each row is `'T'`.

Edit: I tried doing the same above with the `numpy` library instead creating a 2D array of characters and then the replacement works as expected but with the above implementation still not sure whats going on there :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because list multiplication `[] * n` does not create new data, but pseudo copies the list as a reference. Use list comprehension:

```
self.board = [["." for a in range(10)] for b in range(10)]
```

---

Using `[["."] * 10] * 10` does not create new data, but copies the reference to the list `["."]` `10` times

---

Edit as pointed out by `ShadowRanger`

The following is also acceptable:

```
self.board = [["."] * 10 for x in range(10)]
```

Comment: Note: The innermost `list` can be produced by multiplication here, so `[["."] * 10 for i in range(10)]` works just fine. Multiplying any sequence containing *mutable* inner values is the problem, but since the innermost `list` contains immutable `str`, it's okay.

Comment: Ah I see that makes more sense, thank you!